# How can I improve this number2words script

Tags: python

```
import sys

words = {
    1 : 'one',
    2 : 'two',
    3 : 'three',
    4 : 'four',
    5 : 'five',
    6 : 'six',
    7 : 'seven',
    8 : 'eight',
    9 : 'nine',
    10 : 'ten',
    11 : 'eleven',
    12 : 'twelve',
    13 : 'thirteen',
    14 : 'fourteen',
    15 : 'fifteen',
    16 : 'sixteen',
    17 : 'seventeen',
    18 : 'eighteen',
    19 : 'nineteen'
}

tens = [
    '',
    'twenty',
    'thirty',
    'forty',
    'fifty',
    'sixty',
    'seventy',
    'eighty',
    'ninety',
]

placeholders = [
    '',
    'thousand',
    'million',
    'billion',
    'trillion',
    'quadrillion'
]

# segMag = segment magnitude (starting at 1)
def convertTrio(number):
    return ' '.join([words[int(number[0])],  'hundred',  convertDuo(number[1:3])]) # convertDuo(number[1:3])


def convertDuo(number):
    #if teens or less
    if int(number[0]) == 1:
        return words[int(number)]
    #twenty-five
    else:
        return tens[int(number[0]) - 1] + '-' + words[int(number[1])]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    string = []
    numeralSegments = []
    numeral = sys.argv[1]

    if int(numeral) < 100:
        print convertDuo(numeral)
    else:

        # split number into lists, grouped in threes
        for i in range (0, len(numeral), 3):
            numeralSegments.append(numeral[i:i+3])

        numeralSegments.reverse()

        # for every segment, convert to trio word and append thousand, million, etc depending on magnitude
        for i in range (len(numeralSegments)):
            string.append(convertTrio(numeralSegments[i]) + ' ' + placeholders[i])

        # reverse the list of strings before concatenating to commas
        string.reverse()        
        print ', '.join(string)
```

**Warning**: I'm a total python novice. I'm aware there are probably many times more efficient ways of doing things. I'd appreciate any pointers to them.

**Edit**: The code currently only works for numbers whose digit counts are multiples of three. I'd appreciate a suggestion for an elegant way to fix that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this is not homework. This is just an exercise I'm doing to improve my Python skills.

Comment: `string` is a built-in Python module. It is a bad practice to use variable names that conflict with built-in names. You could use a `parts` instead of.

Comment: Have you tried padding the number by zeros (to make a digit count to be multiples of three)?.

Comment: ya, perhaps padding it may be a good idea. Also, i'm currently converting from int to string to manipulate digits. is there a way to do this while in int type?

Comment: Digits?  You mean (number % 10)?  Yes, there are ways to manipulate digits of an int.  (number % 10) is the rightmost digit.

Comment: 'string' is part of the standard lib but is *not* a built-in.

Comment: Check out this link (it is perl, but you should be able to convert it to python fairly easily). http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/math/number/number.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't group digits into "segments" going from left-to-right.   The `range(0,len(),3)` is not going to work out well.  You'll have to write the same algorithm for inserting digit separators.  You start from the right, picking off segments of digits.

What's left over (on the left, get it?) will be 1, 2 or 3 digits.  You've got convertTrio and convertDuo, which handle 3 and 2 digits, respectively.  Somewhere in there is a convert one digit function (can't see it).

If it's not homework, then, here's a proper digit clustering algorithm

```
def segment( n ):
   segList= []
   while len(n) > 3:
       segList.insert( 0, n[-3:] )
       n= n[:-3]
   segList.insert( 0, n )
   return segList
```

Edit

To be more Pythonic, package this as a tidy, reusable module.  The stuff inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` does two things, which should be separated.

Your command-line parsing (anything having to do with `sys.argv` is one thing.  The actual "convert a number" function is something else entirely.  You want to look more like this.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    for number in sys.argv[1:]:
        print number2string( number )
```

Then, your `number2string` function becomes an easily reused piece of this module.

Comment: Thanks. do you have any comments on the general 'python-ness' of the code i've written. Are there things i should have done in a more functional style perhaps? I'm used to very strict oop languages like Java and C#. Thanks

Comment: `number2string` reminds me about `str(number)` e.i. the name poorly communicates the intention of the function. IMO perl's `spell_number` is a better name in this case.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastion: Sorry, but "spell_number" is opaque to me.  Naming is subjective, there's no "clearer", just "what I prefer".  When teaching intro-to-linux there's always someone who objects to "rm" removing a file.  They want to spell remove, "del".  Don't know why.

Comment: @S.Lott: I think the problem is that "string" is very generic, and doesn't tell you much about what form that string takes - "42" is a string representation as much as "forty two" is.  spell_number is  a bit unrevealing too though - I'd go for numberToWords()

Answer (score 3):

Two improvements come to mind:

- 40 is spelled "forty", not "fourty"
- your program needs unit tests

Have a look at the Python [doctest](http://python.org/doc/2.5/lib/module-doctest.html) and [unittest](http://python.org/doc/2.5/lib/module-unittest.html) modules.

Comment: hehe, i wrote that note down on my paper, and *still* got it wrong. :(

Answer (score 2):

Instead of slicing digits, use modular arithmetic to separate the units.  This function will convert a number less than 100 using the given data structures.

```
def convert(n):
    q, r = divmod(n, 10)
    if q < 2:
        return words[n]
    result = tens[q-1] # offset because tens is missing first null value
    if r:
        result += '-' + words[r]
    return result
```

Then use convert recursively to support larger numbers, e.g., start with divmod(n, 100) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Numbers and plural words as spoken English](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413172/) will help a little. A little dated though - 4 May 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Check out source for [Number::Spell](http://search.cpan.org/src/LHOWARD/Number-Spell-0.04/Spell.pm) Perl module. It is short and can be easily ported to Python (if it has not already been done).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone reading this is looking for a numbers to words script, have a look at [inflect.py](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect)

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()
p.numwords(123456789)
```

gives

```
'one hundred and twenty-three million, four hundred and fifty-six thousand, seven hundred and eighty-nine'
```