# converting integer input to words

Tags: cpu-word

I have to write a program such that I give it a three digit input and it converts it into word format. example:

```
input = 907
output = nine hundred seven
```

I can easily figure out how to give the hundred position output. I can divide the input by 100 and then store the whole part of result into a new variable. and then if the variable has value, let's say `7` make another new variable of character type and give it a value `seven` using if conditionals.

But I can't figure out what to do for tens and ones. I mean when there is a number like `907`, do I write something so that it gives me the correct output.
PS I just started programming and don't know the best method to do this.

What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: This is a /very/ common question and a bit of googling will find code to do it in almost every common language available.  Actually coding one yourself isn't too hard.  Start at the least significant digits, grab three of them and work from there.   The `thousands` `millions` and `billions` can be kept in an array and just reference which 'group of 3' you are looking at.

Comment: It would be good to tell us what language you're using, and show code for what you've got so far.

Comment: in the list of answer to this question: [How can I improve this number2words script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289735/how-can-i-improve-this-number2words-script) you can find links to good algorithms implemented in various programming language; googling a bit you can find a lot of other resources like this: [Numbers and plural words as spoken English (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/413172/) and even some multi human language implementation like efaps java classes hosted con google code

Answer (score 0):

There are good libraries they can perform this kind of task for you. However you can get the result using :

```
int intput = 907;
int hundred = input/100;
int ten = input/10%10;
int one = input%10;
```

To use in loops you can use:

```
int one = input%10;
int ten = input/10%10;
int hundred = input/10/10%10;
int thousand = input/10/10/10%10;
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
// Convert numbers to words
// copyright 25th July 2006, by Stephen Chapman http://javascript.about.com
// permission to use this Javascript on your web page is granted
// provided that all of the code (including this copyright notice) is
// used exactly as shown (you can change the numbering system if you wish)
// American Numbering System
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];
// uncomment this line for English Number System
// var th = ['','thousand','million', 'milliard','billion'];

var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

function convertNumberToString(s) {
    s = s.toString();
    s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
    if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
    var x = s.indexOf('.');
    if (x == -1) x = s.length;
    if (x > 15) return 'too big';
    var n = s.split('');
    var str = '';
    var sk = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
            if (n[i] == '1') {
                str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
                i++;
                sk = 1;
            } else if (n[i] != 0) {
                str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
                sk = 1;
            }
        } else if (n[i] != 0) {
            str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
            if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
            sk = 1;
        }
        if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
            if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
            sk = 0;
        }
    }
    if (x != s.length) {
        var y = s.length;
        str += 'point ';
        for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
    }
    return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
}
```