# Convert a dollar amount to a string

Tags: c++, arrays, processing

The assignment is this (taken from a website)

> Write a program that displays a simulated paycheck. Theprogram should ask the user to enter
> the date, the payee's name,and the amount of the check. It should then display a simulated
> check with he dollar amount spelled out, as shown here.
>
> Date: 11/24/2007
>
> Pay to the Order of: JohnPhillips $1920.85
>
> One thousand nine hundred twenty and 85 cents

I have quite a lot of it done, but the problem comes with how to print out the text dollar amount. this is what I have so far (note, this is just the functions that are part of a class)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "TextVersionOfNumber.h"


using namespace std;

string TextVersionOfNumber::convertNumberToText()
{

    string one_19[] = {"", "one", "two", "three", "four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", 
        "eleven", "twelve",
        "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen",
        "eighteen", "nineteen"};

    string twenty_90[] = {"","","twenty","thirty","forty",
        "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};


    double amount;
    int a = amount/1000;
    int b = (amount/100) - (a*10);
    int c =  (amount/10) - (a*100) - (b*10);
    int d = amount - (a*1000) - (b*100) -  (c*10);
    int cents = (amount*100) - (a*100000) - (b*10000) -  (c*1000) - (d*100);

    if (a >= 1)
        amount_string = one_19[a] + " thousand " + one_19[b] + " hundred " 
}

void TextVersionOfNumber::setAmount(double DollarAmount)
{
    DollarAmount = amount;
}
```

The if statement is where I was going to start doing a large nested if block, but my teacher says "I will not accept a program with if statements instead of array processing! Decisions structures will need to be used to implement this logic; however using 10-20 "if" statements is not acceptable!"

Clearly, I'm supposed to use this logic known as "array processing" but I haven't the slightest clue as to what it is, and thus far, my searches have only turned up initializing and various ways to fill and access an array. The question is: What the hell is array processing and how can I use it to finish this code? Don't finish the code for me, I learn best by examples lol.

Okay, I did it, ran into a few problems, fixed it, and it all works now. I called her and she said it was okay to use a few if statements, but she didn't want me using only if statements to do it all. So, thanks guys!

Comment: Manually list (in order) which dollar amounts use which indices in either array. What do you notice?

Comment: nothing... I notice nothing. Although now I feel like the concept is extremely simple...

Comment: Don't forget to give credit to SO in your assignment. [Convert integer to words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332979/converting-integer-input-to-words).

Answer (score 1):

Well you could get the first digit of each number and run it through some arrays:

```
int thousands = amount / 1000;
int hundreds = amount % 1000 / 100;
int tens = amount % 100 / 10;
int ones = amount % 10;
int decimal = amount - static_cast<int>(amount) * 100; 
//takes out the decimal and multiplies by 100
final_string = th_string[thousands] + hu_string[hundreds] + te_string[tens] + o_string[ones] + to_string(decimal) + "cents";
```

Of course you have to implement `_string`: I'm not going to do the HW for you

Comment: That part is taken care of, I need a way to print out "a << thousand << b << hundred << c << d" while also accounting for the possibility that the number could be 1304.42 or 34.21. I would use nested ifs, but she doesn't want that.

Comment: Well in my code: for number "1304.42": thousands = 1, hundreds = 3, tens = 0, ones = 4 and decimal = 42. This should be easy to print out if you implement the arrays properly. The only place where I find there would have to be an `if` statement is if `tens == 1`, to account for the -teen numbers

Answer (score 0):

> ***"I have quite a lot of it done, but the problem comes with how to print
>   out the text dollar amount."***

Well, you could try something like this:

```
string _0_9[] = { "", "one", "two", ..., "nine" };
string _0x_9x[10] = { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", ... "ninety" };
string _x0_x9[10][10] = {
    _0_9, // (not sure if you can do this, otherwise you can set it another way)
    { "ten", "eleven", "twelve", ..., "nineteen" },
    _0_9, _0_9, _0_9, _0_9, _0_9, _0_9, _0_9, _0_9
}; 
string tags[] = {"", "hundred", "thousand", "million", ...}
```

So you can try to break a number down 3 digits at a time:

```
int tagIndex = 0, value = 12345, remainder;
while (value > 0) {
    remainder = value % 1000; // (== 345 first time)
    value = (value - remainder) / 1000; // (move the numbers down, so 12 is left)
    int hundredsIndex = value / 100; // (== 3 first time)
    int tensIndex = value % 100 / 10; // (== 4 first time)
    int onesIndex = value % 10; // (== 5 first time)
    amount_string = _0_9[hundredsIndex] + tags[(hundredsIndex>0?1:0)]
                    + _0x_9x[tensIndex] + _x0_x9[tensIndex][]
                    + tags[tagIndex]
                    + amount_string;
    tagIndex = tagIndex + 1; // "thousand" will be used on next loop pass
}
```

This is only an example - I'm pulling out C++ from my head and haven't had time to test any of it (so it probably won't compile, and you're computer may implode into a small singularity), but hopefully you get the idea ;).  Also, I didn't handle cents, but you can figure that out. ;)